# deploy angular 4 app to my ftp pagespeed insight blank preview

Tags: angular

After creation of my simpl website with

```
ng new project1
```

I built to the prod with

```
ng build --prod
```

i upload the dist folder in my FTP.

if i call the URL [ng.daoo-art.com](http://ng.daoo-art.com) that works fine

but when i test my website in google pagespeed insight i got a blank preview [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fng.daoo-art.com)

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issu and I Solved it using:

```
ng build --env=prod --base-href .
```

or

```
ng build prod --base-href .
```

I Hope you can do it now.